# select-all feature on list of check-boxes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox

I have a list of items along with their associated check-boxes.

And I'd like to achieve the following:

- select/un-select all items in list using "Select All" checkbox.
- select/un-select individual items in list.
- when all items are selected and any of the selected items is clicked, u-nselect "Select All" checkbox.

Most of these steps are working as expected, except, when I :

- select all list-items by checking the "Select All" checkbox
- un-checking any of the selected items
- then again checking "Select All" checkbox.

This causes that any list-item I un-selected before clicking on "Select All" checkbox, remain un-selected.

[image]

It looks as if (for some reason) the internal state of the checkbox is not being changed in this case.

Although, when :

- all list-items are un-selected and I select any of the list-items
- then check the "Select All" checkbox

it correctly selects all list-items. So I'm a little confused as why it's not working in the other case mentioned above.

Note: The main reason , I don't want to store state for every item in the list, is that I will be using this in a table with virtual-scroll. Which fetches data page by page.. So I don't have access to all items data, hence, I only store either items I manually selected or un-selected.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }

  public list = [
    "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"
  ];

  public selected = {
    ids: [],
    all: false,
    all_except_unselected: false
  };

  public toggleSelectItem( id: number, event: MouseEvent ): void {
    if ( this.selected.all === true ) {
      this.selected.all = false;
      this.selected.all_except_unselected = true;
      this.selected.ids = [];
    }

    if ( this.selected.all_except_unselected === true ){
      this.selected.ids = [ ...this.selected.ids, id ];
    } else if ( this.selected.all == false && this.selected.all_except_unselected == false ) {
      if ( this.selected.ids.indexOf( id ) === -1 ) {
        this.selected.ids = [ ...this.selected.ids, id ];
      } else {
        this.selected.ids = [ ...this.selected.ids].filter( itemId => itemId !== id );
      }
    }
    console.log(this.selected.ids);
  }

  public isSelected( id: number ): boolean {
    if ( this.selected.all === true ) {
      console.log(id, 'selected all')
      return true;
    } else if ( this.selected.all_except_unselected === true ) {
      console.log(id, 'selected all except unselected');
      return true;
    }

    console.log(id, this.selected.ids.indexOf( id ) >= 0 ? 'selected' : 'unselected');
    return this.selected.ids.indexOf( id ) >= 0;
  }

  public toggleSelectAll(): void {

    if ( this.selected.all == false ) {
      this.selected.ids = [];
    }
    this.selected.all = !this.selected.all;
    this.selected.all_except_unselected = false;
    console.log('selected all ', this.selected );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="selected.all" (change)="toggleSelectAll()"> Select All 
<br>
<br>

 <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
   <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected(i)" (change)="toggleSelectItem(i, $event)"> {{ item }}<br>
 </div>
```

[Old code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ujcgh?file=null)

[Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gac1sj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uncheck a checkbox even if one among the list is unchecked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784744/how-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-even-if-one-among-the-list-is-unchecked)

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself** not only on an external site. See [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is really messy. I would not bother with the booleans, you can make the checks on the array on the fly and the checkboxes will update the state correctly.

Here is the updated code, You can make further modifications but you can get the idea of how this works.

https://angular-hvbfai.stackblitz.io

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }

  public list = [
    "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"
  ];

  public selected = {
    ids: []
  };

  public allSelected() {
    return this.selected.ids.length === this.list.length;
  }
  public toggleSelectItem(id: number, event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (this.selected.ids.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      this.selected.ids = [...this.selected.ids, id];
    } else {
      this.selected.ids = [...this.selected.ids].filter(itemId => itemId !== id);
    }

    console.log(this.selected.ids);
  }

  public isSelected(id: number): boolean {
    return this.selected.ids.indexOf(id) >= 0;
  }

  public toggleSelectAll(): void {

    if (this.allSelected()) {
      this.selected.ids = [];
    } else {
      let i = 0;
      this.list.forEach(element => {
        if (this.selected.ids.indexOf(i) === -1) {
          this.selected.ids = [...this.selected.ids, i];
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
    console.log('selected all ', this.selected);
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="allSelected()" (change)="toggleSelectAll()"> Select All 
<br>
<br>

 <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
   <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected(i)" (change)="toggleSelectItem(i, $event)"> {{ item }}<br>
 </div>
```

Comment: not sure what browser you tested this on, but it has the same bug as in my version.
Right after app has been loaded, check "Select All"checkbox, then un-check"item2" (as part of that action "Select All" gets un-checked), then again check the "Select All" checkbox (to select all items). And you should see that  "Item2" remained un-checked. Which is wrong, cause all items should be selected. Tested in Chrome v72 and MS Edge

Comment: @Alexus sorry, the link I posted was your link, already updated with my link. You can copy and paste my code in your stackblitz also.

Comment: it's not exactly what I wanted but it helped me to better understand as where the issue is and fix my code.